# Why does only one of these SQL statements work?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Why does the first SQL statement not execute, and the second one does?

1.

```
select e.employee_id, e.last_name, e.salary as "SALARY"
from employees e
where employees.salary > (select avg(salary) from employees) 
order by SALARY;
```

2.

```
select e.employee_id, e.last_name, e.salary as "SALARY"
from employees e
where e.salary > (select avg(salary) from employees) 
order by SALARY;
```

Answer (score 5):

Because you have already *define an alias* for the table name `employee`.

So in the `WHERE` clause, you need to *use the alias*, not the table name since it is not valid anymore.

```
SELECT e.employee_id, e.last_name, e.salary as "SALARY" 
FROM   employees e 
WHERE  e.salary > (select avg(salary) from employees) 
    -- ^ ALIAS should be used, not the tableName
ORDER  BY SALARY;
```

This might be a little *off-topic* but this is an additional info.

The Order of SQL Operation is as follows:

- FROM clause
- WHERE clause
- GROUP BY clause
- HAVING clause
- SELECT clause
- ORDER BY clause

Since you have supplied an alias for the table name on the `FROM` clause, anything the follows in the order of operations is *now referring to that alias given* and not on the table name itself.

Comment: You may like [this edited query of you](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/105580/where-did-we-meet)? (Added post link)

Comment: @hims056 I like you edited query but I can't get any result. With this values tested: `1370508` and `491243` I can get result on the [Original Query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/90422/where-did-we-meet) but not on this one [your edited query](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/105580/where-did-we-meet) But I'm not really sure why change just the column name would lead to no result returned.

Comment: Ohh Actually the problem was: I edited that query for Meta. See the result for [Main site](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/105580/where-did-we-meet?AskerId=1370508&AnswererID=491243) :)

Comment: @hims056 my bad `:)` hey how or where did you know about the aliases that can be converted into links such as `ID AS [Post Link]` or on this [TOP-N Country](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/87307/top-n-users-in-the-country) `Id [User Link]`?

Comment: That are called magic columns. Available in it's [FAQ](http://data.stackexchange.com/faq)

Answer (score 0):

To make the first one work, replace all occurrences of "e" with employees and remove the "e" alias:

```
select employees.employee_id, employees.last_name, employees.salary as "SALARY"
from employees 
where employees.salary > (select avg(salary) from employees) 
order by SALARY;
```